# Text chopped off in IE 11 when clicking a direct comment link

Tags: bug, design, internet-explorer

I like the new meta stack design.  But some of the text is getting chopped off in IE 11.

> [image]

Refresh didn't appear to help.

**Edit trying to help with recreating it:**  When someone comments on my question. Little (1) shows up in the menu bar at the top. I click on that and it brings you to [Link here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230382/text-chopped-off-in-ie-11?noredirect=1#comment756793_230382)

```
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230382/text-chopped-off-in-ie-11?noredirect=1#comment756793_230382
```

That made the bug show up again in this post.

It doesn't appear to happen if I view a question directly from the site via:     Questions -> click any question -> [Link here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230382/text-chopped-off-in-ie-11)

```
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230382/text-chopped-off-in-ie-11
```

This leads me to wonder if its something with the extra parameters being sent in the url from viewing a comment or because its coming from the menu.

```
noredirect=1#comment756793_230382
```

Comment: +1 for the screenshot...

Comment: Where exactly you see it happening?

Comment: Added some info to see if I can help you recreate it.

Comment: It's has been so long since I use IE, just to reproduce this bug. +1. (Wow, it's pretty bad actually, chopped from question title until above footer)

Comment: Yup [reproduced now from IE](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Yk1TV.png). Nasty bug!

Comment: Don't ask me why. But I have Stack open on the left monitor in IE, and G+ in chrome on the right monitor.  The only Logical reason I have for doing this is then I have to icons in my task bar one for IE for chrome.  Chock it up to a woman's logic if you like :)

Comment: @Tim nice find, didn't notice that before.